# Coif linear regression issue

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am completing data analysis for a project and keep meeting the same error for the code below:

```
coeff = pd.DataFrame(lr.coef_, X.columns, columns=['Coefficient'])
```

> AttributeError: 'LinearRegression' object has no attribute 'coef_'

preceding line of code outlines the following about lr variable:

```
lr= LinearRegression()
lr.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = lr.predict(X_test)
```

Here are the imported modules (I think)

```
import six
import sys
sys.modules['sklearn.externals.six'] = six

from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
from sklearn.externals.six import StringIO  
from six import StringIO
from IPython.display import Image  
import pydotplus

from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA
from pmdarima.arima import auto_arima
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, mean_absolute_error
import math

# Also:

# Statistics packages 

import statsmodels as statsmodels
import statsmodels.api as sm 
import statsmodels.tsa.api as smt 
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import grangercausalitytests
from statsmodels.stats.diagnostic import het_arch
from statsmodels.compat import lzip 
from pandas.plotting import lag_plot

# Machine learning 

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier, DecisionTreeRegressor, plot_tree
from sklearn.svm import SVC, SVR
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier, GradientBoostingClassifier, RandomForestRegressor, GradientBoostingRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report 
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn import metrics

# Added print(type(lr), lr) to the data frame with the following outcome

ERROR:root:Internal Python error in the inspect module.
Below is the traceback from this internal error.

<class 'sklearn.linear_model._base.LinearRegression'> LinearRegression()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2882, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-175-3e14ef09cf34>", line 2, in <module>
    coeff = pd.DataFrame(lr.coef_, X.columns, columns=['Coefficient'])
AttributeError: 'LinearRegression' object has no attribute 'coef_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 1823, in showtraceback
    stb = value._render_traceback_()
AttributeError: 'AttributeError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 1132, in get_records
    return _fixed_getinnerframes(etb, number_of_lines_of_context, tb_offset)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 313, in wrapped
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 358, in _fixed_getinnerframes
    records = fix_frame_records_filenames(inspect.getinnerframes(etb, context))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/inspect.py", line 1502, in getinnerframes
    frameinfo = (tb.tb_frame,) + getframeinfo(tb, context)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/inspect.py", line 1460, in getframeinfo
    filename = getsourcefile(frame) or getfile(frame)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/inspect.py", line 696, in getsourcefile
    if getattr(getmodule(object, filename), '__loader__', None) is not None:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/inspect.py", line 725, in getmodule
    file = getabsfile(object, _filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/inspect.py", line 709, in getabsfile
    return os.path.normcase(os.path.abspath(_filename))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/posixpath.py", line 383, in abspath
    cwd = os.getcwd()
OSError: [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected
```

Could anyone recommend a solution to this error?

Comment: Why did you write `lr.coef_` if the `lr` object has no attribute `coef_`?

Comment: Can't tell without knowing anything about the `lr` variable

Comment: Hi @mkrieger1, new to python here and I think I may have deleted or omitted a line of code which would have assigned an attribute to coef_ . And idea what that may have been or am I completely off the mark?

Comment: @falafelocelot a preceding line of code outlines the following about lr variable:   lr= LinearRegression()
lr.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = lr.predict(X_test)...... is that helpful?

Comment: @CathalFlannery Please [edit] your question to include that code.

Comment: And tell us what module those are from.  There are many different functions called `LinearRegression`.

Comment: @TimRoberts I have edited the question to provide info about the modules. Is that what you are looking for or should I search for something else further up the workbook?

Comment: That's good, we need that, but that still doesn't show where `LinearRegression` came from.

Comment: @TimRoberts I think I just added what you are referring to!

Comment: Well, then, I'm confused, because that all looks perfectly correct.  Could you please do `print(type(lr), lr)` just before the DataFrame call, to see what it thinks it is?

Comment: Assuming the additional LinearRegression import is the one responsible for the `lr` variable, docs [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html) suggest it should be a valid attribute

Comment: @TimRoberts when you say do it before the DataFrame call, where would that be in the workbook?

Comment: @CathalFlannery on the immediately-preceeding line, in the same cell

Comment: You never said you were using Jupyter.  Can you run this as a standalone script on a command line?  One of the big problems with Jupyter is that it's way too easy to have variables leftover from previous frames.

Comment: @TimRoberts I have added that line and pasted the outcome above. To be honest I do not know-how to run this as a standalone script...

Comment: OK, I looked at the source code.  `self.coef_` is created during `fit`.  If you did `lr = LinearRegression()` / `print(lr.coef_)`, then you would see the results you describe.  The fact that your error says "line 2" suggests that's maybe what you did.